# ASP.NET web.config: What is the default for the debug attribute in system.web.compilation?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

If I don't include the `debug` attribute in the `compilation` element like this:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation />
</system.web>
```

Does it default to `true` or `false`?  Links to sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The default for `debug` attribute in the `compilation` is **false**

MSDN - [compilation Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.100).aspx)

> **debug**
>
> Optional Boolean attribute.
> Specifies whether to compile debug binaries rather than retail binaries.
> The default is False.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the doc - some I wasn't otherwise able to find on my own.

Answer (score 11):

The default value is false, but beware of [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx).

So, if in a specific web.config file you find:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation />
</system.web>
```

It may very well be that the actual value it true, if there is a web.config file at a higher level with:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

If you use the the IIS configuration editor, you can see the actual values. A drop down list allows you to inspect the values set at a higher level.
[image: Configuration inheritance at work]

You can see that the value of debug=true. Not because it is set in the web.config file at the application level, but at the root site level.

Answer (score 5):

The Default value will be false.

Here is a [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.71).aspx) about the compilation tag for web.config.

Answer (score 2):

The default is **false** as described by previous answers.

If debug=true is specified in Machine.config, every web app's web.config will inherit it and it will be treated as default then.

Comment: To find the path of `machine.config`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325492/2173353