# ASP.NET MVC currency / culture issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, currency

In a number of places in my code I'm converting values into currency using the ToString c method:
    .ToString("c")

On my dev machine this correctly formats values in line with my regional settings and as a result the currency displays as such:
£100.00

However on the production server it is ignoring the windows regional settings and instead defaulting to a US based setting:

$100.00

I had a similar problem with DateTimes but converted to the ISO 8601 format.

Where is the production server is picking this up from?

Comment: Are your dev machine's and prod server's regional setting same? Check out from `Regional Settings -> Formats -> Additional settings -> Currency -> Currency symbol`

Comment: They are yes.  Both are setup to English (United Kingdom), £ for currency, DD/MM/YYYY etc

Comment: Check also [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx) on both machine.

Answer (score 3):

Set proper culture in your `web.config` file:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

Check this article out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: I appreciate this answer but am intrigued still as to why the difference between the two machines.  There must be a global setting somewhere...

Comment: `machine.config`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config

Comment: Or in any inherited `web.config` from parent folders.

Comment: I've diffed the machine.config's and they're identical and so are the web.configs in that folder

Comment: Then there might be different settings in client browsers.

Comment: There's only one client browser - the one on my dev machine

Comment: There are ways where the culture can be taken from: 1) Client browser settings (if `<globalization culture="auto" />`); 2) `web.config` `<globalization culture />` setting. The setting can be inherited from some parent `web.config`, so I think in your case it must be somewhere there; 3) Server regional settings; 4) It can be set explicitly in the code. I can also admit that appropriate request header can be added or edited on some proxy server, but it seems to be far fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can force Culture in your ToString function

```
number.ToString("c", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other solutions mentioned here but kept running into the same issue noted in the original question.

In the end, my problem was resolved by changing who the app pool was running as in IIS. When set to LocalSystem, the US $ would always show for currency, regardless of what I set my region to or how I modified my web.config files.

When I changed the app pool to run as any other interactive user on my machine, then it immediately began reflecting the region settings.