# ASP.NET MVC 4 Template project fails to find 'MySql.Web

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new project in ASP.NET MVC 4. Normally you just hit F5 and it runs as a semi empty project. Instead I'm getting:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web,
>   Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This makes no sense. I have no such entries in my config file and dont event want to use MySql. What has changed in MVC 4? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your machine.config file has been changed, I suggest take a look at that in either of these locations:

32-bit

```
x:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config
```

64-bit

```
x:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config
```

as suggested by Petoj in this post

[Where Is Machine.Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue ..adding following tags to web.config file worked for me :

```
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear/>
              <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider"
                   type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"
    />
          </providers>
      </membership>

      <roleManager defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear/>
              <add name="SimpleRoleProvider"
                   type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"
    />
          </providers>
      </roleManager>
```