# Which Machine.config to modify

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have installed 1,2,3,3.5,4 .net framework on my server, now they all have machine.config file, which one should I modify to see changes for my web applications in IIS 6.

Comment: Look at the framework version of your application pool to decide. It should be either 2.0 or 4.0 so you can change based on which one is in use based on your application pool

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config, I'm linking for reference but this question does have a specific part about IIS 6 so it's not a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each version of .NET is installed in different folder and have different machine.config file independent of each other.

```
ASP.NET 1.x uses %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322
ASP.NET 2.0 / 3.5 x86 uses %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
ASP.NET 2.0 / 3.5 x64 uses %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
ASP.NET 4.0 x86 uses %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
ASP.NET 4.0 x64 uses %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

To see which version your application is running on print

```
Response.Write(System.ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration().FilePath);
```

Comment: **machine.config** is in **Config** subfolder in these folders