# Nuget Issue - 404 for all packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have been having some troubles with the nuget package manager. Firstly, I was suddenly unable to search nuget. If I tried to install something through the packet manager console, I would get the following error

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async
Install-Package : The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.Bcl.Async
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

To solve this, I had to add a package source. Both of these seemed to work

```
http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc
```

This worked at the time. I searched and downloaded a package succesfully. The next morning however, I am now getting a different error. If I try and download anything from the nuget UI, I get a 404 message after I select the package that I want.
If I try and download something from the package manager console, I get the following error

```
The source at All [(Aggregate source)] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\MYUSERNAMEHERE\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.Bcl.Async
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I asked a friend to try and download the package that I wanted, and he was able to without issue. Which leads me to believe this is a problem on my end. Any ideas?

Comment: This usually happens to me if I was on VPN or something and it altered the Connection Proxy settings from Auto-Detect to something specific in Network settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using fiddler to inspect soap messages from a WCF service that I wrote, and I followed this tutorial to set it up

http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-01-08/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler

In this tutorial, it instructs you to add the following in to the machine.config file

```
<!-- The following section is to force use of Fiddler for all applications, including those running in service accounts -->
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy
                enabled = "true"
                useDefaultCredentials = "true">
        <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

When I removed this property, my Nuget issues went away

Comment: Where is machine.config? Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config

Comment: This answer is a life savor, no one can expect to that a fiddler proxy setting will have side effect on nuget.