# PagedList.Mvc 4.5.0 won't install, nuget manager not working VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, nuget-package

[image]

[image]

[image]

Nuget keeps showing the message: "Retrieving information...".

- I tried to clean nuget cache,
- reinstalling nuget package manager,
- I downloaded the package and tried to install it offline

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem solved..
If someone has this problem in the future, make sure you have the "PagedList" package installed (not "PagedList.Mvc").
Such stupidity cost me 4 hours...

Comment: Hi wojas, I have added your tips into my answer and you can consider accepting it. If you have further concern, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the suggestion and to improve this case, I have added your answer to help other community members handle similar issue.

**Solution**

Install `PagedList` nuget package directly and the problem will go away.

**Further**, and add some tips for some confusion,

**Actually**, when you install `PagedList.MVC 4.5.0`, it will also install the dependency `PagedList 1.17` at the same time. And in my side, I did not face the same issue when installing .

[image]

So maybe your `nuget.config` has some issues or you have added `defaultProxy` on `web.config` file.

**Suggestion to make a clean environment**

**1)** close VS, delete `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config` file,

delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

then restart VS IDE.

**2)** check on your mvc project, and delete [defaultProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25929021/12450747) on `web.config` file.

**Then**, try to install this again.

**Besides**, you could try the **suggestions** or try the **solution** above which can solve your issue. And if the suggestions make no sense, try the **solution** directly.