# MySql Connector/NET 6.9.5 Install Fail

Tags: mysql, installation, connector

See image for error example:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCIn7.png

I am having trouble installing the latest version of Mysql connector. I previously had 6.8.3 installed. I uninstalled every mysql product I had. I actually had a hard time uninstalling 6.8.3 I had to use a Microsoft utility which finally removed it.

Which can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall

Any ideas on what I can do to get this installed?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm responding to a quite old question, but this is just in case it can help anyone. After trying to upgrade 6.9.4 to 6.9.8 without success using the MySql installer, i found out that the process is quite dependant on the machine.config contents. In my case, my machine config had this element commented:

`<system.web>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
        <!--add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web.v20, Version=6.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" /-->
      </providers>`

I just deleted the commented element and the mysql installer process ran withouth errors.
To find machine config in your system:[Where Is Machine.Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config)