# Decrypting the .ASPXAUTH Cookie

Tags: php, .net, cookies, encryption, .aspxauth

When I login to a website, my browser receives a cookie with the name "ASPXAUTH". I want to decode the data in that cookie. The string is as shown below:

```
ASPXAUTH=D462EB927A9965A39980BC91D741D7E7A3B5432F2E1936F583D0CC050706F94D2A61B72EFF60464F8CA679CC7A0F4C73D04C7FE0CA3C5F25BEF7CF375642EFE776956CE4581797F4B45C530FE8826E3B6EEA58140B90B0B7EACECC152DA1715157E51D5A63C41AAF9E70178E63BF8B7CD9C6C2D7171DB945E29C07AF472E4A6C8332936C7C7FC12C76D580E9382663104F126414
```

Is it possible to decode this, using PHP or another language?

Comment: it's not clear answer ... i want decryption key found in my Machine.config , where i can find that ?

Comment: See this post to find the location of your machine.config file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config

Comment: @Charles the site that create coocki aspxauth not mine and i dont  have permission to accsess machine.config

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the following three concepts： [FormsAuthentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)、[FormsAuthenticationTicket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)、[authentication]

I hope this can give you some inspiration.