# Again: mySql Connector.Net upgrade 6.9.5 to 6.9.8

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

On Windows 10 I have a mySQL installation. I want to upgrade or delete it. Either fails. It seems that the main problem is with the Connector.net. It cannot be removed or upgraded.

I found this solution [Cannot Uninstall MySql Connector .Net 6.9.3, failure at MySql.Web.v20.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29113685/1446005) posted on March 18 this year.

S. Weinberger had a reference machine to compare the `machine.config` file with. In the `machine.config` I can find keys for MySql, but with wich keys should I replace to make uninstall work?

I tried: uninstall with Windows Control Panel, then CCleaner, ... nothing is able to uninstall. I tried to upgrade or remove it with the MySql Utilities, it fails.

The problem is discussed since years in different forums, a lot of guesses, but no clear solution.

And it seems to block my Reference from mySL Workbench 6.3 to the mySql-server as well.

especially there are several machine.config files in ../Windows/Microsoft.Net/Framework/version/CONFIG/ (and ../framework64/.. and for different versions.....)

Comment: this does not seem to be about programming. Maybe it is a question for database or server forums? (stackexchange.dba or ... serverFault?)

Comment: thats true, sorry. but how do i move it to th appropriate forum?

Comment: seems you could be lucky after all: check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814244) by S.W.

Comment: I wanted to say: it seems the question could be "on topic",even if that link does not help you much