# ODP .NET - add a database reference

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a project in Visual Studio 2017. One of the used databases is an Oracle server.

To avoid using the classic .NET Oracle client, which has been deprecated, I've been trying to use ODP .NET.

I've installed it, next to my classical Oracle client. (I have multiple clients installed...)

Whenever I try to add a database reference to a Visual Studio project (I do all my Db work in Visual Studio) I get the following error: Failed to find the default tnsname.ora files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio ODP Unmanaged Driver - Failed to find the default tnsnames.ora file (12c )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233472/visual-studio-odp-unmanaged-driver-failed-to-find-the-default-tnsnames-ora-fil)

Comment: What do you mean by "add a database reference"? Do you mean connect to a database via code? Show your code!