# requiresQuestionAndAnswer set to false in web.config but RequiresQuestionAndAnswer is true at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, sqlmembershipprovider

In an ASP.net web application I have defined the following Membership provider in the web.config:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="MyServer" name="MyServer" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
      enablePasswordReset="true" 
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

When I run the application in the debugger, the property `Membership.Provider.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer` is `true`.

Why? And how can I fix this?

Update: Ar tuntime, the `Membership.Providers` collection contains two instances of Provider that are almost identical. The differences are:

- The first Provider has Name=="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" and RequiresQuestionAndAnswer==true
- The second Provider has Name=="MyServer" and RequiresQuestionAndAnswer==false.

Now trying to figure out where the first one is coming from.

Comment: Does the provider name in the debugger match the name of your provider ("MyServer")?

Comment: @MeidanAlon the provider name in the debugger seems to be "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider". At the same time, it's showing the correct SQL connection string so it looks like it's the right one.

Comment: That's weird, I'd try adding defaultProvider="MyServer" inside membership and <clear /> to <providers>

Comment: @MeidanAlon Adding <clear /> before the <add> causes a ConfigurationErrorsException. Setting defaultProvider="MyServer" on <membership> did the trick. Thank you. Would you like to post this as an answer? Also - the question remains why there are two Providers instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the follow up question, the mystery providers is defined on a lower level config file, named machine.config, which is the server-wide parent config file for all asp.net sites running on the machine. See some more details at the [MSDN page for asp.net config hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The fix for my problem is to specify in web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyServer>
```

The reason why there's an "extra" Provider at run-time is that it's defined in my **machine.config** file. [Here's how to find yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config).

Credit for fix goes to @meidan-alon and credit for root cause goes to @ken-egozi :)