# Server error in "/" Application (ASP.NET MVC + Devexpress)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Can't run my application because of error above.

1) Controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PullAccountTable()
    {
        DataSet account = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;

        try
        {
            string connString = @"Server = VDI01\Sqlexpress; Database = RealEstate_RiskEngine_DB; Integrated security = true;";
            string query = "select * from ACCOUNT";

            conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(account, "ACCOUNT");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            da.Dispose();
        }

        return PartialView("_AccountPartial", account.Tables[0]);

    }
```

2) "Index" view

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Risk Engine";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Action("PullAccountTable")  

}
```

3) "_AccountPartial" view

```
 @model System.Data.DataTable
@using DevExpress.Spreadsheet

@Html.DevExpress().Spreadsheet(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "ACCOUNT";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "AccountController", Action = "PullAccountTable" };
    //settings.DownloadRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "SpreadsheetPartialDownload" };
    settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.Height = 500;
    settings.ReadOnly = false;
    settings.RibbonMode = SpreadsheetRibbonMode.Ribbon;
    settings.PreRender = (s, e) =>
    {
        MVCxSpreadsheet ss = s as MVCxSpreadsheet;
        Worksheet ws = ss.Document.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;
        ws.Import(Model, true, 0, 0);
    };
}).GetHtml()
```

4) Screenshot of the error message
[image]

5) Project config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="resources" type="DevExpress.Web.ResourcesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/> 
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Utils.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v17.2.Core, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v17.2.Core, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.Mvc5.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Spreadsheet.v17.2.Core, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpreadsheet.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Docs.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="4096" requestValidationMode="4.0" executionTimeout="110" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" validate="false" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <globalization culture="" uiCulture="" />
    <pages validateRequest="true" clientIDMode="Predictable">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Utils" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpreadsheet" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Spreadsheet"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>    
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DevExtreme.AspNet.Data" publicKeyToken="982f5dab1439d0f7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DevExpress.Data.v17.1" publicKeyToken="b88d1754d700e49a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-17.1.4.0" newVersion="17.1.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v17.2, Version=17.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <devExpress>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" theme="Default" customThemeAssemblies="" />
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
    <settings rightToLeft="false" checkReferencesToExternalScripts="true" doctypeMode="Html5" accessibilityCompliant="false" />
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
  </devExpress>
</configuration>
```

6) View config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebApplication1" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Utils" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI" />
        <add namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpreadsheet" />
        <add namespace="DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

What I did to fix the problem:

- have add `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>` to `<system.web>` in Project config file. After that, I had new error:

  [image]

After that, I removed line 118 from the config file, but got the previous error:

[image]

Right now I am stuck and don't know, what to do next.

UPDATE 1:

Was trying to play with machine.config file, but was not helped:
[New error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG7fu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

-Leave line 118 in your config.

-Find the [machine.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config).

-Look for httpRuntime tag in this file then delete it from there. Don't close the file so you can undo or keep a backup of it. If something gets broken revert machine config at its previous state.

Why it happens:

Sometimes when you install components or frameworks they configure themselves in the machine config (happened to me with ODAC, ODP.NET and other oracle tools), but your solution searches the configuration first in machine.config then in the app.config, so it finds it two times.

Hope that solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this solution was not helped me. Se UPDATE 1 in my question.