# Can't open DBML files - .Net data provider missing?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 on a new computer, and I am trying to work on my C# project which uses LINQ. Previously, I have worked with Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows 7 machine with SQL Server 2012. Now I need to switch to Windows 10 and SQL Server 2017.

I have installed Windows 10, SQL Server 2017 and Visual Studio 2017 Professional. In the setup of Visual Studio, I activated "LINQ to SQL tools" as well as "SQL Tools".

The project loads and I can actually compile and run everything.

But when I try to open a DBML file in the IDE, I get several error messages:

> "Der Extenderprovider konnte keinen Extender für dieses Objekt
>   zurückgeben." (Translated: **"The extender provider could not return an
>   extender for this object"**)

as well as

> "Der angeforderte .Net Framework-Datenprovider kann nicht gefunden
>   werden. Er ist ggf. nicht installiert" (Translated: **"The requested .Net
>   Framework data provider can not be found. It is probably not
>   installed"**)

***Other problem (probably same origin):***

When I try to add a data source and select "Microsoft SQL Server", I receive the message:

> "Das Verbindungseigenschaftenobjekt muss vom Typ
>   SqlConnectionProperties oder OleDBSqlConnectionProperties sein."
>   (Translated: 
>   **"The connection property object must be of type
>   SqlConnectionProperties or OleDBSqlConnectionProperties"**)

In the drop box I can select ".NET Framework-Datenanbieter für SQL"
and ".NET Framework-Datenanbieter für OLE DB"
Both don't work.

[image]

***Here is a screenshot of my setup***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had to changed the [machine.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config) ( %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\(*version*)\config\machine.config ) and remove the extra line `<DbProviderFactories/>`. This solves both problem plus a third problem where I couldn't use the View-Designer in SQL Management Studio.

[image: Machine.config extra line]

Update: This issue still happens with a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2022! It's amazing that Microsoft doesn't fix this showstopper after nearly 4 years.

Comment: I had the same issue after migrating to a new HDD. Copying the machine.config files from the old drive seems to have cleared up the issue for me.