# Root config for .NET framework apps

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Like we have the root web.config for IIS deployed web apps, do we have a root app.config for console applications in .NET framework?

Comment: what sort of config do you mean? like console window settings? or your app(s) own settings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config